# What are my options for building a Tizen app in Github Actions?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I am building a Tizen/Samsung application. I dig through lots of documentation and blog articles on how to do it but I am on a stage where I want my Github Actions to build the app so I can distribute it to others, like QAs or internal testing. And - So far I haven't found a good solution to achieve a complete CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a Tizen package can be easily done with Tizen CLI. Basically you can do any kind of thing such as installing Tizen Studio and running a CLI build inside your GitHub workflow file. Here is an example workflow:

```yaml
name: build

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-wgt:
    timeout-minutes: 10
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Tizen Studio
        run: |
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt install -y pciutils zip libncurses5 python libpython2.7
          sudo apt clean
          curl http://download.tizen.org/sdk/Installer/tizen-studio_4.1/web-cli_Tizen_Studio_4.1_ubuntu-64.bin -o install.bin
          chmod a+x install.bin
          ./install.bin --accept-license $HOME/tizen-studio
          rm install.bin
      - name: Install Tizen packages
        run: |
          $HOME/tizen-studio/package-manager/package-manager-cli.bin install \
          Certificate-Manager NativeCLI WEARABLE-5.5-WebAppDevelopment-CLI
      - name: Run Tizen CLI build
        run: |
          export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tizen-studio/tools/ide/bin
          tizen build-web -- [PathToYourProject]
          tizen package -t wgt -- [PathToYourProject]
      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: my-wgt
          path: [PathToYourProject]/[ProjectName].wgt
```

Note that the script has not been tested and may not work (actually I don't have any experience with Tizen web apps). I just wanted to give you a simple idea of how to get started.

The remaining thing is to sign the output app with your certificate (using the `-s` option when running the `package` command) while keeping the certificate private from your public Docker or GitHub repo. You'll have to figure out how to do it yourself.